# Sequentially increasing GUID for an RSS

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, rss, guid

I have a bit of code that produces an RSS feed, now one of the errors in the formatting is that the GUID does not increase, or is not a unique number. The code for writing the RSS is as follows:

```
    rss_start="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
        <rss version="2.0" ">

            <channel>
                <title>Your title</title>
                <link></link>
                <description>Your discription</description>

    """

    rss_end="""

            < href="" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
            </channel>
        </rss> """

    def description(item):
        return item

    def title(item):
        return item.split('\n')[0]

    def link(item):
        return '' + item.split('\n')[0]

    for counter, item in enumerate(inp):
        if item:
            rss_items.append("""
                    <item>
                        <title>%s</title>
                        <link>%s</link>
                        <description>%s</description>
                        <guid>counter</guid>
                    </item>""" % (title(item),link(item),description(item)))

    rss_output=rss_start+''.join(rss_items)+rss_end
```

Any tips methods or comments to steer me in the correct direction to produce a sequentially increasing GUID would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks SM

Comment: Guid does not increase makes no sense whatsoever, thought you could probaly do it. Where's the definition of counter?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [uuid](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) module. It provides functions for generating uuids in different formats. E.g.:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('16fd2706-8baf-433b-82eb-8c7fada847da')
```

The objects returned by the different `uuid`-functions implement `__str__`, so to convert them to a `str` call e.g. `str(uuid.uuid4())`.

However, GUIDs generated by this module are not sequentially increasing, because this is not a common use case. Why do you want your GUIDs to be sequentially increasing? Perhaps you need something different here, or a combination of counter / uuid.